# DHARMa: quantile deviations detected

Tags: residuals, diagnostic

I am in the process of fitting a GLMM to my count data:

[image: data]

I used a zero-inflated poisson with quadratic term:

```
M5_tur_pois_nb <- glmmTMB(production ~ poly(Treatment_Num,2,raw=T)*Source_Salinity +Rarity+ Region+poly(Treatment_Num,2,raw=T)*Max_ramets_num+replanted+(1|Genotype)+(1|Unit/Replicate),
                    data = turions_produced_1_turion_planting,zi=~1,
                             family=poisson)
```

I could use a second opinion on these diagnostic plots from DHARMa. The qqplot looks great and there is no overdispersion, but I can see some patterning in the quantile plot. I'm wondering how much is too much deviation from the dashed quantile lines?

```
M5_tur_pois_nb_res <- simulateResiduals(M5_tur_pois_nb)
plot(M5_tur_pois_nb_res)

testDispersion(M5_tur_pois_nb_res)
```

[image: diagnostics]

[image: dispersion]

I plotted the residuals against the predictors as has been recommended in other posts, and the variation seems to be coming from Treatment:

```
plotResiduals(M5_tur_pois_nb_res, turions_produced_1_turion_planting$Treatment, xlab = "Treatment", main=NULL)
```

[image]

Is this variation among treatments cause for concern? Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned by these plots. The QQ plot is excellent and the histogram shows no under/over dispersion, as you mentioned. The quantile plot isn't perfect, but you can't ever expect it to be. I would say that there is a mild departure what what we would like, but it is not a big cause for concern.

Comment: Hi Carrie, if you install the lates version of DHARMa, you will get a formal test for variation among treatment!